# Failing to deploy war file to tomcat server from manager portal

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my .war file to tomcat server using the manager/html portal. However, when hitting the deploy button, the upload won't start and an error page comes in at the browser window. I am in need of clarification about what is actually creating the issue.

I tried changing the port address manually, and tried out with multiple .war files. The problem still persists.

```
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.427 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

I am getting the above server trace when the upload fails. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the error on browser ?

Comment: This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET